I add SwiftUI in TableViewCell, but sometimes TapGesture doesn't call back
//
//  RCChatMessageCell.swift
//  Runner
//
//  Created by chenrui on 2024/6/13.
//

import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class RCBaseMessageCell: UITableViewCell {
    fileprivate func createSwiftUIContent(_ parentViewModel: RCConversationViewModel,_ viewModel: RCMessageViewModel) {
        self.selectionStyle = .none
        let customCotentView = MessageFactory.createMessage(type: viewModel.message.type, viewModel: viewModel)
        let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: customCotentView)
        hostingController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.hostingController = hostingController
        
        self.contentView.addSubview(hostingController.view)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            hostingController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor),
            hostingController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.trailingAnchor),
            hostingController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor),
            hostingController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor),
        ])
    }
    
    func update(parentViewModel: RCConversationViewModel, message: ChatMessage_ChatMessage, index: Int) {
        self.parentViewModel = parentViewModel
        let viewModel = RCMessageViewModel(message: message,parentViewModel: parentViewModel)
        viewModel.index = index
        createSwiftUIContent(parentViewModel, viewModel)
        
        self.hostingController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }
}


When I touch the text, sometimes it doesn't print 123. It seems like it doesn't receive the touch gesture. Does anybody know how I can solve this issue? Or another way to avoid this bug.
This bug only happens in iOS 18.1 and iOS 17. But iOS 16 works fine.

AnyView(
Text(
parentViewModel.getShowTextByMessage(
message: viewModel.message)
)
.onTapGesture {
print("123")
}
.font(Font.system(size: 16))
.foregroundColor(Color(WaterTheme().textParagraph)))   this is my swift ui code

Use UIHostingConfiguration instead of UIHostingController. It's simple. You don't need even subclass UITableViewCell.

And don't use AnyView. Use ViewBuilder + some View

i tryed it but still not callback sometimes
if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
self.contentConfiguration = UIHostingConfiguration {
Text("123").onTapGesture {
print("123")
}
}
}

i found other view catch the gesture,only ios18.1 have this bug
